# change text position to bottom left on screen rotate android

Tags: android-layout, android

I have to display a text (id- **text_view** in the code below)at the bottom left of  the screen. Find below the code snippet for the text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:text="SampleText"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It is coming at bottom left but for only Portrait mode. When i rotate screen to landscape mode the text remains there, It should also be rotated to Bottom left of the screen.

Please help me how to achieve this on screen rotation

Comment: post your full layout code

Comment: @Boopathi i have updated

Comment: i checked the code,it is working fine in both modes

Comment: Problem is the text should always come in bottom left. Which is happening in Portrait but not in landscape. On rotate to Landscape mode, the text remains in bottom right Which was drawn for Portrait mode

Answer (score 0):

1:- First Change the FrameLayout to RelativeLayout.

2:- Set layout_gravity of textview to left|bottom.

Comment: Ashutosh it didnt help